# Ionic: Any example or link related to tabs bar

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to know is there any link of example or tutorial where I can find tabs other than default tabs in ionic 5? I need something similar or other simple good tabs in ionic anyone can help with link example or tutorial thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is **Super Tabs** which are swipable tabs.
Github Reference link :
https://github.com/zyra/ionic-super-tabs/blob/master/README.md

The ui of these tabs could be enhanced as you want in the gif you added if you where a good designer ( using css and animation ).